# Should memory be freed just before return statement in main?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, memory-management

Consider this small program:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int *i = new int;
    //do something with i, where i is involved all the time
    return 0;
}
```

As a matter of good style and to show that you actually know you must free memory allocated on the heap you normally add `delete i;` just before return statement.

But will it do any harm if leaving `delete i;` out?

UPDATE: Please do not flame each other in comments. I do know that just to be on safe side and just as the matter of good style and so on I should free allocated memory. The question is, can it be ommitted *safely* in this *particular* case.

Comment: The OS will reclaim the memory when the program exits, so technically speaking if the program exits like that, you don't have to free it. But it's good practice to do so.

Comment: This situation is a good candidate for smart pointers.

Comment: This question is too localized so I'm voting to close. The answer is, in your PARTICULAR case (which isn't even clear -- what OS are you running this on?), that it MAY be safe. All in all, it's not an insightful question and answers are too scattered to be of any value.

Comment: Also if your situation is exactly like this where you allocate something on the free store in main and have a choice whether to `delete` it or not just before returning, you might just as well use a stack variable instead of a free-store variable and a pointer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There won't be any harm. The OS deallocates all the process's memory, when it dies.

Nevertheless not deleting your variables is a bad style as it hinders the use of tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Having no idea what OS the above will be run on, this answer may be simply inaccurate or blatantly incorrect.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco, I see your point. But as no sane person would use C++ on a DSP/embedded system, I assume Roman B. wants to run his code on a Windows >= 95 or (some, any) *nix.

Comment: Yes, latest Windows and Linux are the OSs I'm interested in. Valgrind is nice point.

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't matter, since modern operating systems tend to clean up a program's memory after the program terminates. That being said, I'm pretty sure some older systems *don't* do the clean up, so if you're targeting any of those systems then you'll definitely want to be careful.

Regardless of both those points, wouldn't you sleep better knowing that your code doesn't leak?

Answer (score 4):

No, it won't do any harm as the system cleans all of the non deleted ones automatically.
the harm will if you write code that excepts to use everything until the program terminates, and then you discover you need to run it multiple times and you will have memory leaks between iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Your memory will be freed on a modern OS, but that doesn't mean the destructors will be called.

It's a bad practice. Don't do it. Use smart pointers instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you use memory tracking tool to find memory leaks, unbalanced allocs/deallocs from your top level would show up as leaks. This will distract you from your task of finding the real memory leaks. Other than that, you are safe: OS will free up the memory and other resources for you.

Answer (score 1):

Memory shall be retrieved by most operating system and donated back to heap. But would you ever rely on that ? See i reckon your very specific example is set so that it looks innocent. Yes the program finishes and then operating system snatches back all memory you forgot to de-allocate. The only problem is that as soon as your program gets bigger and will serve whatever purpose and someone lets it running, then you're basically 'stealing' memory that could have been available for other services running.

a) Never waste system resources (memory, processing power, ports, sockets ... )

b) Return whatever you don't need, there are other processes running along with yours.

I reckon you modeled a scenario that basically relies on your application being terminated which does not necessarily have to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this example it would not hurt, since the program will exit anyway and most operating systems should just make that memory available on the heap again. But you should better just put a delete statement after having used the variable.

Answer (score -4):

If you run the code in debug mode, the allocated memory will be tracked differently and will be freed up at program termination. BUT if you run the program in release mode it causes memory leak and if you run your program over and over, ultimately all memory on system will be  allocated and not freed up causing low memory and all other bad things.

so it is more than just good coding style.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. The OS ultimately does the memory clean up. Further most debuggers don't care about memory allocations. Tracking pointer usage is very expensive. It would hurt even basically debugging, when used needlessly.

Comment: I think what you mix this with is the fragmentation of the memory, what can happen in the long run.